# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyrealsense2' with LiDAR Camera 515

Tags: python, camera, measure, lidar, realsense

The project I'm working on requires the use of a Lidar Camera L515, and my current goal is to measure objects in real-time. I found a guide to get me started (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_gzcp8dURbU&ab_channel=Pysource), however even though I installed what was required at the beginning of the tutorial (`pip3 install opencv-python` and `pip3 install pyrealsense2`), I'm still receiving the error listed in the title. I tried using the same install command in the command prompt application and ubuntu (I installed it in both places just in case) but no luck. Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: What is the output of `<python> -m pip freeze`, where `<python>` is the Python executable you use to run your script?

Comment: @MichaelRuth It's a long list, but it does say "pyrealsense2==2.48.0.3381". Is there something else I should be looking for?

Comment: I just followed the installation instructions and had no issue importing `pyrealsense2`. You should check that `sys.path` includes the site-packages directory which contains `pyrealsense2`. Otherwise, there's not much I can do since I can't reproduce the problem. Really, this looks like a path issue, i.e. you've installed the packages to a location inaccessible to your Python interpreter.